# Can I use FilesystemCache for Doctrine2 caching in production before Zend Optimizer+ can co-exist with apc or xcache?

Tags: caching, doctrine-orm, zend-optimizer

Doctrine2 doc recommends Apc/Memcache/Xcache for both metadata cache and query cache [[reference]](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.1/reference/configuration.html#metadata-cache-recommended). However, we cannot use Apc or Xcache because we are using zend optimizerPlus. They don't work together at the moment. I'd prefer to not use Memcache as well because it involves network time (we have multiple dedicated memcache servers).

Do any of you guys have **production** experience of using \Doctrine\Common\Cache\FilesytemCache for doctrine? As linux OS will cache these cache files in memory, I feel it should be good enough before we can use apc/xcache with zend optimizer+ (hopefully in php 5.5). But any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: I've used filesystem cache in production on a linux vm with django and it seems to work nicely, even though the docs say it isn't production ready.  Sounds like a reasonable thing to do to me - linux should give very fast cached access to files.  Make sure you have noatime turned on in your fstab (but this is the default for most distros anymore).

Comment: Good to know the noatime setting. My devbox (centos) is recording the cache files' access time. So maybe redhat doesn't make it as default.